# Import Talend Jobs in management console (Talend Cloud) to Talend Studio?

Tags: talend

I am trying to connect my local `Talend studio` with `Talend cloud` though I was successful in connecting studio to cloud, but I am unable to access the jobs that are there in the environments in `Talend` management console using my `Talend studio`. Is there any configuration in `Talend studio` or in TMC which can make those Artifacts in `Talend cloud` environment visible to me?

`TMC Environments`

[image]

`Artifacts`

[image]

Comment: Not sure to fully understand this : you have problems to access projects when launching the studio, whereas you can see those projects on TMC ? if so, it should be a role-attribution problem.